# Unable to get the nth column data due to changing output of uptime command

Tags: awk, output, columns, printf, uptime

Below is the output of uptime from Solaris where I am extracting the third last column:

```
uptime
8:30pm  up 23 day(s), 17:46,  5 users,  load average: **2.79**, 1.79, 1.53
```

I always need to get the third last column highlighted in bold above i.e. `2.79`

```
echo '8:30pm  up 23 day(s), 17:46,  5 users,  load average: 2.79, 1.79, 1.53' | awk '{ print substr($10, 1, length($10)-1) }'

Output:
2.79
```

But at times it fails when uptime output has `18 hr(s)` instead of `17:46` as seen below:

```
echo '8:44pm  up 23 day(s), 18 hr(s),  5 users,  load average: 1.08, 1.12, 1.22' | awk '{ print substr($10, 1, length($10)-1) }'

Output:
average
```

A simple solution could be searching for the columns from the last column minus 3 i.e 3rd column from last as the last three columns are always numerical and don't change. However, I m not sure how-to.

Can you please suggest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read `man cut` and do something like:

```
uptime  | cut -d, -f4 | cut -d: -f2
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this out.

```
awk -F ':' '{ print 0+substr($NF, 1, -1+index($NF,","))}'
```

Answer (score 0):

To always get the third last column all you need to do is to count backwards from the end of the line instead of forwards from the front of it:

```
awk '{print $(NF-2)+0}'
```

For example:

```
$ echo '8:30pm  up 23 day(s), 17:46,  5 users,  load average: 2.79, 1.79, 1.53' | awk '{print $(NF-2)+0}'
2.79

$ echo '8:44pm  up 23 day(s), 18 hr(s),  5 users,  load average: 1.08, 1.12, 1.22' | awk '{print $(NF-2)+0}'
1.08
```